# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: filesystem

Tags: java

i have written a program for reading the contents of my microsoft word document file. actualy my requirement is to get the document map of the word.doc, i throught of getting started with reading the doc file my code is ..

```
public static void readParagraphs(HWPFDocument doc) throws Exception
        {
            WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
            /**Get the total number of paragraphs**/
            String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
            System.out.println("Total Paragraphs: "+paragraphs.length);
            for (int i = 0; i &lt; paragraphs.length; i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("Length of paragraph "+(i +1)+": "+ paragraphs[i].length());
                System.out.println(paragraphs[i].toString());
            }
        }
```

---

```
but am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: filesystem
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:218)
    at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.<init>(HWPFDocument.java:158)
    at com.honeywell.corept.srd.ReadDocFileFromJava.readMyDocument(ReadDocFileFromJava.java:25)
    at com.honeywell.corept.srd.ReadDocFileFromJava.main(ReadDocFileFromJava.java:18)
```

this exception am not able to solve this. please help.

Comment: What is there on line 25 of ReadDocFileFromJava.java

Comment: HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please? In your posted code i can not see `HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);`

Comment: public static void readMyDocument(String fileName){
  POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
  try {
   fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
   HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

   /** Read the content **/
   readParagraphs(doc);

   int pageNumber=1;

   /** We will try reading the header for page 1**/
   readHeader(doc, pageNumber);

   /** Let's try reading the footer for page 1**/
   readFooter(doc, pageNumber);

   /** Read the document summary**/
   readDocumentSummary(doc);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check if you have two copies of POI JAR on your classpath.

If yes, keep single copy.

Comment: But am also trying to get the Document Map (Index for word doc). Not able to figure out how can you please help on that.

Comment: Please check the dependency , for windows 7 Excel files  
                                                                                             
                              <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.16</version>
  </dependency>